# in Azure ML SDK V2 how can we publish a pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

we want to create a pipeline and then publish this pipeline as a endpoint for applications to call when needed. We dont want to schedule this pipeline. in SDKV1 we had an option of
published_pipeline1 = pipeline.publish() but something like this is missing in SDK V2.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment (17.07.2023), there is no equivalent of `pipeline.publish()` in Azure ML SDKv2 (`azure-ai-ml 1.8.0`).

The only solution is to publish the pipeline from the UI.

You can also check the discussion at this link, people mentioning the same problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1033206/publishing-aml-pipelines-with-sdk-v2

Comment: Dont know why publish isnt included in SDK V2. Strange ..  .... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1159059/publishing-pipeline-endpoints-with-sdk-v2 also points to the same problem.

Comment: I know. Since I answered your question, kindly accept my answer/upvote according to what you consider optimal